# Is there a possibility to follow where/when a macro is being redefined

Tags: macros

I am currently trying to solve several bugs for witch it would be convenient
if there exists a system in LaTeX where you can "spy" on a certain macro.
I am interested in where/when a macro is being redefined. Idealy
you could say `\spy\mymacro` and it would output

```
`file.cls -> \newcommand\macro`,
`package.sty -> \renewcommand\macro`
```

and so on.

Comment: texlive comes with a `texdef` utility along those lines, but I usually use `grep` the standard unix search, although I'm on windows)

Comment: `texdef -t latex -p foopackage command name` is useful for a quick check and then have a look into the package or class file. And for standard commands, `texdoc source2e` is a good source

Comment: Have you tried the [`unravel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unravel?lang=en) package? It's pretty cool!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it: for example a package could say

```
\newcommand{\redefinefoo}[1]{\renewcommand{\foo}{#1}}
\providecommand{\foo}{whatever}
```

and a redefinition of `\foo` might take place anywhere

```
\redefinefoo{something else}
```

is issued, which could be itself hidden in some other macro.

Redefining `\def`, on which also `\renewcommand` is based, is out of the question, because it would break almost everything.

However, you could say `\tracingassigns=1` in your document and in the log file you'd find

```
{changing \foo=\long macro:->whatever}
{into \foo=\long macro:->something else}
```

Based on the location in the `log` file you may be able to guess where the redefinition is taking place.